# How to send image with React to AspNetCore

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I am trying to get a file on my react application like so:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <label htmlFor="Images">Images:</label>
    <input type="file" id="Images" onChange={this.onChangeImage} accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>
    <button type="submit" value="SubmitImage" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And onSubmit looks like this:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.value === "SubmitImage"){
        fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/projects/edit/image/" + this.props.projectId + "/add", 
        {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({photo: this.state.Images[0]})
        });
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to receive this on my backend like so:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("projects/edit/image/{id}/{toDo}")]
public void EditProjectImage(string id, string toDo, IFormFile photo)
{
    if(toDo == "Add")
    {
        var result = mContext.Projects.Single(project => project.Id.Equals(id));  
    }
}
```

(ignore the lack of logic inside the if statement, I am currently just trying to have this function run)
What am I doing wrong? I have tried using [FromBody], using formdata but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormData` for sending files

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("photo", this.state.Images[0]);
fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/projects/edit/image/" + this.props.projectId + "/add", 
{
    method: "PUT",
    body: formData 
});
```

And leave `IFormFile photo` as is. Model binder binds parameters from form data by default which is correct behavior in this case. Or you may add `[FromForm]` to this parameter which is effectively the same in this case.